# How to get previous value while datetime is set as index

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy

I have pandas dataframe with datetime as index:

```
                     sys  dia  pul  map
datetime                               
2011-07-20 10:34:00  125   80   60   95
2011-07-20 11:00:00  103   67   55   79
2011-07-20 11:30:00  106   72   53   83
2011-07-20 12:00:00   97   61   50   73
2011-07-20 12:31:00  109   71   49   83
2011-07-20 13:00:00  103   68   49   79
2011-07-20 13:30:00  107   66   48   79
2011-07-20 14:00:00   76   49   50   58
2011-07-20 14:31:00  108   73   57   84
2011-07-20 15:00:00  108   66   47   80
2011-07-20 15:30:00  101   65   47   77
2011-07-20 16:00:00   96   69   46   78
2011-07-20 16:30:00   92   59   46   70
2011-07-20 17:00:00  104   73   46   83
2011-07-20 17:30:00  108   73   46   84
2011-07-20 18:00:00  100   70   53   80
2011-07-20 18:30:00  106   72   52   83
2011-07-20 19:00:00   96   64   55   74
2011-07-20 19:30:00   97   60   47   72
2011-07-20 20:30:00  104   65   51   78
2011-07-20 21:00:00  105   63   44   77
2011-07-20 21:30:00  102   67   44   78
2011-07-20 22:00:00  110   72   45   84
2011-07-20 22:30:00   83   49   44   60
2011-07-20 23:00:00   85   43   40   57
2011-07-20 23:30:00   84   46   41   58
2011-07-21 00:01:00  101   59   42   73
2011-07-21 00:31:00  100   63   41   75
2011-07-21 01:01:00   89   45   39   59
2011-07-21 01:30:00   98   46   39   63
2011-07-21 02:00:00   86   49   39   61
2011-07-21 02:30:00   84   46   40   58
2011-07-21 03:01:00   90   62   40   71
2011-07-21 03:30:00   90   52   40   64
2011-07-21 04:00:00   90   50   38   63
2011-07-21 04:31:00  107   79   40   88
2011-07-21 05:01:00   92   48   41   62
2011-07-21 05:30:00   89   44   41   59
2011-07-21 06:00:00  129   90   50  103
2011-07-21 06:30:00  118   74   46   88
2011-07-21 07:00:00  114   71   44   85
2011-07-21 07:30:00  116   77   46   90
2011-07-21 08:00:00  123   79   48   93
2011-07-21 08:30:00  120   75   61   90
2011-07-21 09:00:00  124   80   69   94
```

I created dataframe like that:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['datetime','sys','dia','pul','map'])
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])

df.index = df['datetime']
del df['datetime']
```

I had to create sleep time dataframe like that:

```
sleep_time = df.between_time('22:30:01','05:29:59')
```

Now I have to get minimum value from `sleep_time` of `dia` row and get average of three values: a value previous minimum, minimum and next after minimum. Problem is, that the minimum value in sleep_time is first in row. So I have to get previous value from whole dataframe.

`sleep_time` dataframe is this:

```
                     sys  dia  pul  map
datetime                               
2011-07-20 23:00:00   85   43   40   57
2011-07-20 23:30:00   84   46   41   58
2011-07-21 00:01:00  101   59   42   73
2011-07-21 00:31:00  100   63   41   75
2011-07-21 01:01:00   89   45   39   59
2011-07-21 01:30:00   98   46   39   63
2011-07-21 02:00:00   86   49   39   61
2011-07-21 02:30:00   84   46   40   58
2011-07-21 03:01:00   90   62   40   71
2011-07-21 03:30:00   90   52   40   64
2011-07-21 04:00:00   90   50   38   63
2011-07-21 04:31:00  107   79   40   88
2011-07-21 05:01:00   92   48   41   62
```

So, if the minimum value is row:

```
                     sys  dia  pul  map
datetime                               
2011-07-20 23:00:00   85   43   40   57
```

,then I have to get average of `dia` col from 3 rows:

```
                     sys  dia  pul  map
datetime
2011-07-20 22:30:00   83   49   44   60
2011-07-20 23:00:00   85   43   40   57
2011-07-20 23:30:00   84   46   41   58
```

But as you can see,

```
2011-07-20 22:30:00   83   49   44   60
```

this row is not included in `sleep_time` data frame because it's one index before.

So question is, how to simply search row in dataframe by index and get the previous and next value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think better is use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for index from column `datetime`.

Then need [`get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) for position of `Datetimeindex` and then select by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html).

But need `max` and `min` for first and last row of `df` (I think not filtered `df`, so no previous (sample1) and no next (sample3) row, because not exist).

```
df = df.set_index('datetime')
```

instead

```
df.index = df['datetime']
del df['datetime']
```

---

```
d = '2011-07-20 10:34:00'
pos = df.index.get_loc(d)
df1 = df.iloc[max(pos-1,0): min(pos+2,len(df.index))]
print (df1)
                     sys  dia  pul  map
datetime                               
2011-07-20 10:34:00  125   80   60   95
2011-07-20 11:00:00  103   67   55   79

d = '2011-07-20 11:00:00'
pos = df.index.get_loc(d)
df1 = df.iloc[max(pos-1,0): min(pos+2,len(df.index))]
print (df1)
                     sys  dia  pul  map
datetime                               
2011-07-20 10:34:00  125   80   60   95
2011-07-20 11:00:00  103   67   55   79
2011-07-20 11:30:00  106   72   53   83

d = '2011-07-21 09:00:00'
pos = df.index.get_loc(d)
df1 = df.iloc[max(pos-1,0): min(pos+2,len(df.index))]
print (df1)
                     sys  dia  pul  map
datetime                               
2011-07-21 08:30:00  120   75   61   90
2011-07-21 09:00:00  124   80   69   94
```

Comment: `df = df.set_index('datetime')` is not working correctly, because when I try to create new dataframe from `df.between_time('22:30:01','05:29:59')`, then program says that `TypeError: Index must be DatetimeIndex`

Comment: I adit answer, I think simpliest code - instead `df.index = df['datetime']
del df['datetime']`

Comment: Ok, now it's working with index settings. I will try with this sample code andgive you the answer if it will works. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I tried your sample on my data and it works perfectly without doubts! Thank you so much again!

Comment: Glad can help. Nice day!